# Ошибка в программе: invalid syntax

Tags: python

Это текстовая игра в которой мы должны по очереди с ии вытаскивать фиксированное кол-во камней из кучи и побеждает тот после чьего хода больше не остается камней.
Собственно сама программа :

```
import random 
t=[1,2,3,4]
p = 0
q = random.randint(1,3)
print('Введите число камней, от 4 до 25 включительно: ', end='')       
n = int(input())
if n > 4 and n < 25:
    while n>0:
        print('ваш ход:')
        z = int(input())
        if z>4 or z<1:
            print('неверное количество камней')
            break
            exit(0)
        else:
            n = n - z
            print(n)
        print('ход компьютера')
        n = n - t[q]
        print(n)
        p = p + 1
    if ( p % 2 ) != 0:
        print('победа ии')
    else:
        print('победа человека')
else
    break
    print('Некорректный ход:'n')
```

У меня возникла следующая проблема:
в последней строке, где должно указываться действие в случае некорректного ввода кол-ва камней, программа выдает ошибку `invalid syntax`. Cкорее всего из-за нереальности выполнения else, но что же делать в таком случае, ведь требуется указать что была совершена ошибка и надо вывести неверно введенное кол-во камней (как в последней строчке).

Comment: то, что у вас в тексте нечетное количество кавычек, вас не смутило? Если вы "начинающий програмист" (с одной "м"), то пора уже понимать, что ошибка синтаксиса никак не связана с "нереальнстью выполнения" какой-то части алгоритма.

Comment: вы явно что-то плохо знаете применение `break`

Answer (score 2):

```
else
    break
    print('Некорректный ход:'n')
```

во-первых - после `else` надо двоеточие `else:`

во-вторых - какой `break`, если нет цикла

в третьих - внутри `print` лишняя кавычка или просто остаток `'n'`, это убрать надо

```
print('Некорректный ход:')
```